# Resolving _class not in classpath_ error without doing it manually in a k8s Jenkins instance

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins

I have installed a k8s cluster (v1.25.4+k3s1) and I have deployed a [jenkins image](https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/jenkins) to that cluster ([using this guide](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/kubernetes/)) which means that I have the following installed:

| Name | Version |
| --- | --- |
| Jenkins | v2.375.1 |
| jvm | 11.0.17+8 |
| [Kubernetes plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/kubernetes/) | 3743.v1fa_4c724c3b_7 |

When I then try to set up workers on this setup [using another guide](https://chathura-siriwardhana.medium.com/configure-jenkins-with-kubernetes-e3175e02ca8), I get this error (when starting the job):

> `Jan 10, 2023 7:47:16 PM WARNING org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.pod.retention.Reaper watchCloud`
>
> `failed to set up watcher on kubernetes`
> `io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: No httpclient implementations found on the context classloader, please ensure your classpath includes an implementation jar`
>   `at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.HttpClientUtils.getHttpClientFactory(HttpClientUtils.java:164)`
>   `at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.HttpClientUtils.createHttpClient(HttpClientUtils.java:145)`
>   `at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.DefaultKubernetesClient.<init>(DefaultKubernetesClient.java:56)`
>   `at org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.KubernetesFactoryAdapter.createClient(KubernetesFactoryAdapter.java:147)`
>   `at org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.KubernetesClientProvider.createClient(KubernetesClientProvider.java:59)`
>   `at org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.KubernetesCloud.connect(KubernetesCloud.java:523)`
>   `at org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.pod.retention.Reaper.watchCloud(Reaper.java:220)`
>   `at org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.pod.retention.Reaper.preLaunch(Reaper.java:122)`
>   `at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer.lambda$_connect$0(SlaveComputer.java:296)`
>   `at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$2.call(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:48)`
>   `at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$2.call(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:82)`
>   `at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)`
>   `at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)`
>   `at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)`
>   `at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)`
>
> `Jan 10, 2023 7:47:16 PM WARNING org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.KubernetesLauncher launch`
>
> `Error in provisioning; agent=KubernetesSlave name: kube-slave-tq3z1, template=PodTemplate{id='282a0649-b2c7-4a9b-9ee2-0721a8da7ed7', name='kube-slave', namespace='devops-workers', label='kube-slave'}`
> `io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: No httpclient implementations found on the context classloader, please ensure your classpath includes an implementation jar`
>   `at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.HttpClientUtils.getHttpClientFactory(HttpClientUtils.java:164)`
>   `at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.HttpClientUtils.createHttpClient(HttpClientUtils.java:145)`
>   `at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.DefaultKubernetesClient.<init>(DefaultKubernetesClient.java:56)`
>   `at org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.KubernetesFactoryAdapter.createClient(KubernetesFactoryAdapter.java:147)`
>   `at org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.KubernetesClientProvider.createClient(KubernetesClientProvider.java:59)`
>   `at org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.KubernetesCloud.connect(KubernetesCloud.java:523)`
>   `at org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.KubernetesLauncher.launch(KubernetesLauncher.java:120)`
>   `at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer.lambda$_connect$0(SlaveComputer.java:298)`
>   `at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$2.call(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:48)`
>   `at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$2.call(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:82)`
>   `at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)`
>   `at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)`
>   `at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)`
>   `at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)`
>
> `Jan 10, 2023 7:47:16 PM INFO org.csanchez.jenkins.plugins.kubernetes.KubernetesSlave _terminate`
>
> `Terminating Kubernetes instance for agent kube-slave-tq3z1`
>
> `Jan 10, 2023 7:47:16 PM INFO hudson.slaves.NodeProvisioner update`
>
> `kube-slave-tq3z1 provisioning successfully completed. We have now 2 computer(s)`

To experiment I tried to run this script ([inspired by this answer](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/issues/4563#issuecomment-1353163296)) in the Script Console:

```java
@Grab(group='io.fabric8', module='kubernetes-client', version='6.3.1')
@Grab(group='io.fabric8', module='kubernetes-client-api', version='6.3.1')
@Grab(group='io.fabric8', module='kubernetes-httpclient-jdk', version='6.3.1')

import io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClient;
import io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientBuilder;

KubernetesClient client = new KubernetesClientBuilder().build()
```

Which gives the same error:

> `io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: No httpclient implementations found on the context classloader, please ensure your classpath includes an implementation jar`

I would prefer not to have to make manual steps to inject jar files into a ready image, so am I missing another Jenkins plugin, or can I have missed something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrade jenkins kubernetes plugin to 3802 and it should work. At least the `No httpclient implementations found on the context classloader` is addressed by that release.

References:

- https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin/releases/tag/3802.vb_b_600831fcb_3

Comment: hmm that version was not available when i made the post - I see it now